# Spring mvc - Callable<String> request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring mvc application. I needed an async request, so I came across a request which returns Callable

**TestController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/views/async", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Callable<String> getViewAsyncWay(){
    return new Callable<String>(){
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return "test-async"
    };
}
```

**test-async.jsp**

```
    <div>This page is delivered with async request.</div>
```

**home.jsp**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('btn-aync-req').on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "<c:url value="/views/async"/>",
                success: function(data){
                    $('#container').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    <body>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="btn-async-req" value="Send Request"/>
    </body>
```

Now when I click on the Send Request, server log says request processed normally and the resource returned is /views/aysnc.jsp (which is my request uri)

I am not able to figure out which step I am making mistake.

To **applicationContext.xml** I have added:

```
<task:annotation-driven/>
```

The normal spring-mvc request in my project works fine.

Comment: Please post your logs that show what you describe. How can you tell that _the resource returned is `/views/aysnc.jsp`_?

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I figured it out. On my windows environment it was not throwing any error, but it wasn't working either.

Finally I moved to ubuntu and I got the real error. In the web.xml I entered following line:

```
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

Now where the above line is supposed to be entered!!

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

And it worked!! And Thanks to @Sotirios Delimanolis, after his comment I moved to linux environment to get the log :)

Also you have to configure Timeout value for the async request. For more detailed explanation check **Timeout** section in the [this](http://spring.io/blog/2012/05/10/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-making-a-controller-method-asynchronous/) link.